# Excel VBA sumproduct with Criteria

Tags: vba, excel

Need help with writing this Excel function into a Macro, please help

> A1=7  B1=1  C1=4
>
> A2=8  B2=2  C2=5
>
> A3=9  B3=3  C3=6

if A1 = A1(7), answers will equal to B1 * C1 = 1*4 = 4

if A1 = A2(8), answers will equal to B2 * C2 = 2*5 = 10

the function works perfectly in the excel cell,

```
SUMPRODUCT((A1:A3=A1)+0,B1:B3,C1:C3)
```

however, the vba doesn't not work.

```
With Worksheets("Sumproduct")
.Range("D1").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct((.Range("A1:A3" = A1)+ 0 , .Range("B1:B3"), .Range("C1:C3"))`
```

Comment: Are you trying to put the function in the cell, or the result from the function?

Comment: You are missing a `)` after `.Range("A1:A3"` try `.Range("D1").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct((.Range("A1:A3") = A1) + 0, .Range("B1:B3"), .Range("C1:C3"))`.  I do not understand the `+0` in the formula, you probably do not need it.

Comment: But you could also use `.Range("D1").Value = Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT((A1:A3=A1)+0,B1:B3,C1:C3)")`

Comment: `.Range("D1").Value = .Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT((A1:A3=A1)+0,B1:B3,C1:C3)")`

Comment: (A1:A3 = A1) = True ,False ,False, +0 will make True/False equal to 1 and 0  and lead to {1,0,0} *{1,2,3}*{4,5,6} =(A1* B1 *C1)+(A2*B2*C2)+(A3*B3*C3)=(1*1*4)+(0*2*5)+(0*3*6) = 4